# Как узнать по API есть ли аватар в вк и в facebook у пользователя?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, api, facebook-api

Как узнать по API есть ли аватар в вк и в facebook у пользователя или нет?

Comment: посмотреть в словаре по апи?

Comment: не могу найти. есть ли вообще такой метод

Comment: @werty, у facebook можно получить пользователя и уже из пользователя посмотреть значение поля для аватара

Comment: у вк также. user.get

Comment: Например вот: [How to fetch profile picture from facebook javascript SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25036493/5275890) и не помешает [Graph API Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api/)